# Expected value of multidinesional symmetric function is zero

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Does anybody know a simple proof of this statement or reference to such proof?

**Statement** 
Let $h: R^n \to R$ be a bounded function, symmetric in its arguments, i.e. for any permutation $\pi$ of set $(1,\cdots,n)$,
$$
h(x_{\pi(1)},\cdots,x_{\pi(n)}) = h(x_1,\cdots,x_n).   
$$
If for any sequence of iid, nonatomic random variables, $(Z_1,\cdots,Z_n)$ the expected value of $h$ is zero, i.e.
$$
E h(Z_1,\cdots,Z_n) = 0,
$$
then  $h$ is identically equal to zero.

Comment: Sorry, I gave a "hint" that may lead to a proof, but now I'm not sure how to complete the proof, so I erased my hint.

Comment: The idea of my "hint" is to use induction on the number of values the random variables can take.  The case $k=1$ considers constant rnadom variables and shows $h(x,x,...,x)=0$ for all $x \in\mathbb{R}$.  You can extend to the case $k=2$ to show $h(x,y,y,y,...,y)=0$ for all $x, y$.  I think you can generalize this, though I don't have time to think about completing the proof. Limiting arguments seem to help.

Comment: Hi Michael,  I've forgot to add an assumption that Z must be nonatomic, sorry!

Comment: What does "nonatomic" mean?  ALso, what is the context of this question, is it a homework problem?

Comment: If by "nonatomic" you mean the expectation property only holds for random variables $Z_i$ with continuous CDF, then the statement is false.  Consider the function $$h(x_1, ..., x_n) =  \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0 &\mbox{ if $(x_1,...,x_n) \neq (0,...,0)$} \\
1  & \mbox{ if $(x_1, ..., x_n) = (0,...,0)$} 
\end{array}
\right.$$ Then $E[h(Z_1, ..., Z_n)] = Pr[(Z_1,...,Z_n)=(0,...,0)]=0$.

Comment: Somewhat similar problem on page 11 http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/calmost/pdfs/36-755_lec.pdf